# What tool can I use to take a screenshot with cypress automation?

Tags: junit, cypress, screenshot, mochawesome

I have a cypress spec.js and I would like to take several screenshots after particular assertion of the whole page several times. I want the screenshot to be available on a folder or in the report.
I have mochawesome and Junit reporter. What is the best screenshot tool I can use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cy.screenshot()` command to take screenshots in cypress. You can read more about it from [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot).

After assertion you can do like this:

```js
cy.get('selector').should('have.text', 'some text').screenshot()
```

You can also directly use the command without chaining into any previous commands like this:

```js
cy.screenshot()
```

You can also add the screenshot name as well like this:

```js
cy.get('selector')
  .should('have.text', 'some text')
  .screenshot('name') //will save screenshot with name.png
```

You can also save the screenshot as per your desired directory as well like this:

```js
cy.get('selector')
  .should('have.text', 'some text')
  .screenshot('path to folder/name')
```

Now you can pass the `capture` options to let cypress know Which parts of the Test Runner to capture. This value is ignored for element screenshot captures.

```js
cy.get('selector')
  .should('have.text', 'some text')
  .screenshot('name', {capture: 'fullPage'})
```

- `viewport` - The application under test is captured in the current viewport.
- `fullPage` - The application under test is captured in its entirety from top to bottom.
- `runner` - The entire browser viewport, including the Cypress Command Log, is captured.